# Branch agent based on multiple if else condition in Jenkins Pipeline Script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I trying to branch the agents based on some if else condition in the Jenkins pipeline script, but in the console output it's giving and below message and stuck.

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline (hide)

[Pipeline] stage

[Pipeline] { (Package_Download_and_Deploy)

[Pipeline] node

Still waiting to schedule task

There are no nodes with the label ‘None’
```

I have written the script something like the below.

```
   
def Physical_FolderLoc=params.Physical_FolderLoc

def NexusLink=params.NexusLink

def Stord_Process_Name=params.Stord_Process_Name

def now = new Date()

def agentLabel

if (params.Physical_FolderLoc == "E:\\users\\desktop\\ucmacros") 
{
    agentLabel = "INT01"
} 

else {
    agentLabel = "None"
}

if (params.Physical_FolderLoc == "E:\\users\\documents\\ucmacros") 

{
    agentLabel = "INT01"
}

else {
    agentLabel = "None"
}

if (params.Physical_FolderLoc == "I:\\users\\desktop\\stp") 
{
    agentLabel = 'INT02'
}

else {
    agentLabel = "None"
}

if (params.Physical_FolderLoc == "I:\\users\\documents\\stp") 

{
    agentLabel = 'INT02'
}

else {
    agentLabel = "None"
}

pipeline { 

    agent none

    options { 

        skipDefaultCheckout() 
    }
    stages {

        stage("Package_Download_and_Deploy"){

            agent {

                label agentLabel
            }

            steps {
                    bat "Echo download the zip to Jenkins_Deployments folder and unzip there, so files should be there after unzip"
                    
bat "wget -P H:\\Jenkins_Deployments ${NexusLink} -O H:\\Jenkins_Deployments\\Nexus.zip"
                    
bat 'Echo Unzip the same Nexus.zip in the same Jenkins_Deployments folder'      

bat "7z e H:\\Jenkins_Deployments\\Nexus.zip -oH:\\Jenkins_Deployments -aoa -r"
                    
bat 'Echo Back up of STP SAS code Files '
                    
bat "copy \"${Physical_FolderLoc}\\${Stord_Process_Name}.txt\" 

\"H:\\Jenkins_Stp_Backup\\${Stord_Process_Name}_backup_${now.format("yyyyMMdd_HHmm")}.txt\""
                    
                }
                
         }
```

Please let me know where I am doing wrong. Also can't we write if(condition) else if (condition) else (condition)!!

In jenkins is there only (if else if else) fashion is available. No else if!

From the above code it's understood that based on particular agent's folder location I am just trying to copy a file from one location to another.

2 variables(NexusLink, Stord_Process_Name) are string parameters and remaining is choice parameter.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: @vitalii please help me, based on your previous post regarding if else groovy script I tried to do, but it seems it's not working at my environment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simplifying your condition? Now you're just potentially overwriting the value of `agentLabel` everytime you go into an `if` statement. Can you try this as I only see two positive outcomes `INT01` & `INT02`, correct?:

```
def agentLabel = 'None'

    if (params.Physical_FolderLoc == "E:\\users\\desktop\\ucmacros") {
        agentLabel = "INT01"
    }
    if (params.Physical_FolderLoc == "I:\\users\\desktop\\stp") {
        agentLabel = 'INT02'
    }
```

Comment: I tried to follow your suggestion, but still the same issue is hindering. In the console output it's printing. "Still waiting to schedule task

There are no nodes with the label ‘None’"

Comment: def Physical_FolderLoc=params.Physical_FolderLoc
def NexusLink=params.NexusLink
def Stord_Process_Name=params.Stord_Process_Name
def now = new Date()
def agentLabel = 'None'

    if (params.Physical_FolderLoc == "E:\\users\\desktop\\ucmacros") 
    {
        agentLabel = 'INT01'
    }
    if (params.Physical_FolderLoc == "I:\\users\\desktop\\stp") 
    {
        agentLabel = 'INT02'
    }

Comment: pipeline { 
    agent none
 options { 
  skipDefaultCheckout() 
 }
    stages {
        stage("Package_Download_and_Deploy"){
   agent {
    label agentLabel
    }
            steps {

bat "copy /y \"H:\\Jenkins_Deployments\\${Stord_Process_Name}.sas\" \"${Physical_FolderLoc}\\${Stord_Process_Name}.txt\" "
}        }} }```

Comment: please suggest. I am not getting like whatever paths I have added in the choice parameter, with same paths only I am comparing, so ideally it should match the string and satisfy the IF condition. why it's not happening I am not getting. In short the agentLabel variable is not catching Node name at runtime.

Comment: Can you print & share the value of that param in the console output? Maybe it is different when you select that value (`params.Physical_FolderLoc`).

Comment: Inside the Pipeline script I had written 
def agentLabel='None'

    if (params.Physical_FolderLoc == "I:\\users\\documents\\stp") 
    {
        agentLabel = "INT02"
    } 
pipeline { 
    agent none
 options { 
  skipDefaultCheckout() 
 }
    stages {
        stage("Package_Download_and_Deploy"){
   agent {
    label 'INT02'
    }
            steps {
     
     bat "Echo Folder:${Physical_FolderLoc} agent: ${agentLabel}"
                
            }
    
         }}}

Comment: Console Output:    
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Package_Download_and_Deploy)
[Pipeline] node
Running on INT02 in C:\Jenkins\workspace\pipeline-development\test
[Pipeline] {

[Pipeline] bat
C:\Jenkins\workspace\pipeline-development\test>Echo Folder: I:\\users\\documents\\stp agent: None 
Folder: I:\\users\\documents\\stp agent: None
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage

Comment: You can see it's by default resolving to None. I removed the None and tried also, but it's resolving to agent: null in that case. Physical folder location I can say properly resolving and coming correctly as per the selection on choice parameter. The output came bcoz I had explicitly provided the Node name this time in agent {label INT02}.  Hope you got it.